# How to connect sql server to thingworx

Tags: thingworx

I've done some research on how to connect thingworx with sql server or postgre to show data on mashup gird. I found out that  I need to import MSSQLConnector_Extension but i've spent days to find where to download these jdbc extension but i couldn't find it in ptcmarketplace. Does anyone have an idea where to download it or another way to connect dbserver to thingworx. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MSSQLConnector_Extension` is for the older versions of Thingworx. AFAIK, from the latest release (i.e., Thingworx 8.0 or above), the database connector comes along with the Thingworx platform by default.

In the Thingworx platform, create a Thing and choose `Database` under the `Base Thing Template` field. Upon saving the Thing entity, the configuration page appears where you can configure the JDBC settings. With the appropriate DB specific configurations, connection between a dbserver and thingworx can be made.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the SQL Server Details in the platform-setting.json, which will connect the DB directly to the Thingworx and creates a separate DB named "thingworx", all the data in the Thingworx goes in to that Particular DB.

```json
"PersistenceProviderPackageConfigs": {
        "PostgresPersistenceProviderPackage": {
            "ConnectionInformation": {
                "jdbcUrl": "jdbc:************/thingworx",
                "password": "**************",
                "username": "*****************"
            }
        }
    }
```